# Syntax of sapply and lapply in r

Tags: r, sapply

I have been looking into ways to separate a list in r based on the index of the sub values and I have seen this piece of code pop up a lot:

```
sapply(myList, "[", 2)
```

I was wondering if anyone would be able to explain this to me as the only syntax that I have used for sapply before is:

```
sapply(myList, Function)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"["` is by itself a function.

when you call `sapply(LIST, "[", 2)` it means extract the second element of each sub-list.

The `2` which you passed goes as an argument to the function `[` making it `[2]`